# "Unexpected token } in JSON" (Firestore connecting through Zapier)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

Attempting to hook up a trigger from Zapier when a Firestore document gets added, Zapier asks for an `orderBy` element. Documentation (https://zapier.com/help/firebase/#creating-a-firestore-structured-query-for-a-trigger) seems pretty straightforward, but I get an error that

```
ERROR: We had trouble finding a sample. The specified query does not contain valid JSON. Unexpected token } in JSON at position 123
```

I tried a couple of variations (see below for 2 examples), but I keep getting the same error each with a different position.
[image]
    "orderBy": [{
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "timestamp"
            },
            "direction": "DESCENDING"
        }],
    (Result: Position 123)

```
"orderBy": [{
  "field": "timestamp,
  "direction": "DESCENDING"
}],
(Result: Position 46)
```

I'm not even sure where Zapier is getting the JSON, so I can't look at the JSON to see if anything is funky.

Does anyone know how to fix, or at least how to view the full JSON file?

Comment: can you update your question with a link to the doc you're reading and a screenshot of the field you're putting the query into?

Comment: Updated, thanks @xavdid

Comment: It looks like the trailing comma after the last `]` is the issue - that makes it non-valid JSON.

Comment: that was it. Thank you!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the trailing comma after the last `]`, which makes it invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's this one trailing comma, which renders the query invalid: `]},}` - that should be `]}}`.

The full JSON can usually be downloaded in the Firebase console; at least for Realtime Database.

And when it complains about JSON syntax, just use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/); most IDE also highlight syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

According to Zapier documentation:

```
"orderBy": [{
        "field": {
            "fieldPath": "someKeyOfYourChoice"
        },
        "direction": "DESCENDING"
    }]
```

This worked for me. There are more cases of troubleshooting, I highly suggest to check the site out if you still experiencing some issues:
https://zapier.com/help/doc/common-problems-firebase#creating-a-firestore-structured-query-for-a-trigger